# Taking values from Python Operator using XCOM and giving it to Bash Operator

Tags: python, bash, airflow

I am a newbie and wanted to create a pipeline such that the Function given to Python Operator takes **variables** and using *XCOM push approach*, give these variables to Bash Operator. Using Bash Operator, I am trying to run the whole python script which requires these **variables** taken from *XCOM push approach*. Could someone help me to create this kind of pipeline.

I am attaching the broken code below. In the below code app.py is the python script which takes count_check and recon_check value. Also can a single bash command pull multiple variables?

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

from airflow.utils.dates import datetime



args= {'owner': 'airflow', 'start_date': datetime(2022, 1, 1) }


def take_args(ti):
    count_check = 'Y'
    recon_check = 'Y'
    ti.xcom_push(key='count', value=count_check)
    ti.xcom_push(key='recon', value=recon_check)



with DAG(dag_id='data-validation-dag-python',
         default_args=args,
         schedule_interval='@daily',
         max_active_runs=1,
         catchup=False) as dag:

    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='Storing_Args',
        python_callable= take_args
    )

    task_2 = BashOperator(
            task_id='task_validation_checks',
            bash_command='cd /root/airflow/dags && python3 app.py 
            {{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids[\"Storing_Args\"]) }}',
            do_xcom_push=False

    )
    task_1 >> task_2
```

Answer (score 0):

`task_ids` is an argument on the method `xcom_pull`. The correct syntax is:

```py
task_2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_validation_checks',
    bash_command='cd /root/airflow/dags && python3 app.py {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="Storing_Args") }}',
    do_xcom_push=False
)
```

Having `task_ids[\"Storing_Args\"]` will tell Python to look up a key named "Storing_Args" in the dictionary `task_ids`, which doesn't exist and will raise an error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'task_ids' is undefined`.

However, this will still not work in your case since you have pushed two XComs with keys `count` and `recon`. If no key is given, Airflow will assign a default key "return_value". When you then call `ti.xcom_pull()` without specifying a key, Airflow will look up XComs with the default key "return_value", which doesn't exist in your case. Therefore, `ti.xcom_pull()` must be called twice, once for each key:

```py
task_2 = BashOperator(
    task_id="task_validation_checks",
    bash_command="cd /root/airflow/dags && python3 app.py {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='foobar', key='count') }} {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='foobar', key='recon') }}",
    do_xcom_push=False,
)
```

Comment: @ Bas Harenslak thanks for the correction, but still the python script app.py is not able to take the values of count_check and recon_check. Could you please tell where I am going wrong?

Comment: You'll need to give more details to answer that question. For example: what is app.py, what did you try, and what is the error you're getting? Check the Airflow task logs to figure out what is being executed.

Comment: In app.py, I am running a loop which reads the Input(csv) file, takes the values corresponding to each column(where **count_check and recon_check** are columns) and perform the various checks corresponding to values taken (such as Y/N) on a table present in a database. This works fine if I run the app.py script in airflow using only bash operator. But now I don't want to take the values of **count_check and recon_check** from csv file and want to give it before running a dag, like I am trying now. I want these values to be catch by the app.py file. (1/2)

Comment: When I check the log file, it says no variable named count_check and recon_check since it is not able to catch the values. Is push and pulling values from XCOM right approach?(2/2)

Comment: I feel there's some missing code. In the code you've shared count_check and recon_check are defined. Please post relevant code and a stack trace. This helps others reproduce and understand the problem.

If you want to set those values externally (not in code, but when triggering a DAG), you might be interested in dag_run.conf: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#passing-parameters-when-triggering-dags.

Comment: bash_command="cd /root/airflow/dags && python3 app.py echo value: {{dag_run.conf['count_check'] }}"

Comment: Bas Harenslak - Is this the right approach, if I am using UI instaed of CLI??

Comment: And How to give two parameters instead of only one?